# Unknown provider: $rootElementProvider when using $injector to get $location service before angular.bootstrap

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-injector

Hello I am trying to manually bootstrap an angular app, but there is some business that needs to be taken care of first.[This](https://blog.mariusschulz.com/2014/10/22/asynchronously-bootstrapping-angularjs-applications-with-server-side-data) article mentions the technique I am interested in.

when I inject this:

```
 var $injector = angular.injector(["ng"]);
 var $http = $injector.get("$http");
```

it works fine, but this:

```
var $injector= angular.injector(["ng", "myApp"]);
var $location = $injector.get("$location");
```

Throws the following error.

```
Uncaught Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $rootElementProvider <- $rootElement <- $location <- $location
```

Is it possible to get $location prior to angular.bootstrap?

Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In order to get the `$location` before bootstrapping, you would basically need to provide the `$rootElement`. One way is to mock it: inject `ngMock` module from `angular-mocks` to get the injector.

```
var $injector= angular.injector(['ng','ngMock',"plunker"]);
var $location = $injector.get("$location");
```

**[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/tD1heV?p=preview)**

Or supply rootElement on your own by creating a mock app and including that while getting the injector.

```
var mockApp = angular.module('mockApp', []).provider({
  $rootElement:function() {
     this.$get = function() {
       return angular.element('<div ng-app></div>');
    };
  }
});

var $injector= angular.injector(['ng','mockApp',"plunker"]);

var $location = $injector.get("$location");
```

**[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/JwKsST?p=info)**

Or other way (based on your feasibility) is to obtain the location from the window using [window.location](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.location).

Also worthwhile noting this thread on [github](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/7023)

Comment: This does answer my question, but did not solve my problem. One of the things I needed from location was the .search method, and location seems to be in a odd state when injected in this way, and the object is returned empty.

Comment: Why dont i just use window.location.search? What is ur ultimate aim.

Comment: I ended up doing just that. There are some factories in our app that innect $location and we needed their functionality pre-bootstrap. I was trying to avoid having duplicate code by using those services.

Answer (score 4):

root element must be in inserted in document.
See http://plnkr.co/edit/OrgStgw4NpjU2LcIFXsB

```
var rootElement = angular.element(document);

var mockApp = angular.module('mockApp', []).provider({
  $rootElement:function() {
     this.$get = function() {
       return rootElement;
    };
  }
});
```