# Using custom services before the application bootstrap in Angularjs Applications

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to use custom services before the application bootstrap.

```
var initInjector = angular.injector(['ng', 'myModule']);

var myCustomService = initInjector.get('myCustomService');

var $http = initInjector.get('$http');

var $q = initInjector.get('$q');
```

And then in the myCustomService I got:

```
angular.module('myModule').service('myCustomService',myCustomService);

 function myCustomService($location, $q){
   // some logic
 }
```

The error I got is :

> Uncaught Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $rootElementProvider <- $rootElement <- $location <- myCustomService <- $location

It seems that the dependencies used in myCustomService cannot be loaded..

There is a way to organise better the pre bootstrap code and logic?

Comment: If you want to do something before angular bootstrap, don't use angular.

Comment: you can't get custom services using `injector` before bootstrap your app

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a late answer, but from the error message posted in the question, it looks like `$location` should be available before the application bootstrap.

To get the `$location` before bootstrapping, you would need to provide the `$rootElement`. One way is to mock it: inject ngMock module from angular-mocks to get the injector.

```js
var initInjector = angular.injector(['ng', 'myModule', 'ngMock']);
var $location = initInjector.get('$location');
```

Also check out [this StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28400389/11550411) and [this GitHub thread](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/7023).