# AngularJS - unknown provider $modal when getting a service from angular.injector

Tags: angularjs, dependency-injection

I have a piece of javascript code which needs to call an angular service. I try to access the service by retrieving the angular module where the service is defined and then getting the service it self:

```
    var messagemanagerModule = angular.injector(['ng', 'portal.services.messagemanager']);
    var messageService = messagemanagerModule.get('MessageService');
    messageService.postMessage('portal', moduleId, 'selectModule');
```

The module and service is defined like this:

```
    angular.module('portal.services.messagemanager', ['modules.modal', 'modules.softlogoff'])
    .factory('MessageService', messageService);

messageService.$inject = ['$rootScope', '$modal', '$translate', 'ConfigurationService'];

function messageService($rootScope, $modal, $translate, ConfigurationService) {
    var service = {
        showMessage: showMessage,
        showSoftLogoff: showSoftLogoff,
        postMessage: postMessage,
        supportedMessages: supportedMessages
    };

    return service;
```

Unfortunately I get the error:

```
Error: $injector:unpr Unknown provider: $modalProvider <- $modal <- MessageService"
```

I think I need to inject $modal, but I don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

The ui-bootstrap library now uses `$uibModal' service.

So you need to inject `$uibModal` service.

```
messageService.$inject = ['$rootScope', '$uibModal', '$translate', 'ConfigurationService'];

function messageService($rootScope, $uibModal , $translate, ConfigurationService) {
var service = {
    showMessage: showMessage,
    showSoftLogoff: showSoftLogoff,
    postMessage: postMessage,
    supportedMessages: supportedMessages
};

return service;
```

Comment: I don't think that is the problem. I have no problem calling the MessageService from another controller.
When I use $uibModal the application faults durring startup:
Unknown provider: $uibModalProvider <- $uibModal <- MessageService <- ContextManagerService

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to include the ui.bootstrap module as a dependency of your module:
include ui.bootstrap in you dependencies:

```
angular.module('portal.services.messagemanager', ['modules.modal','modules.softlogoff','ui.bootstrap'])
```

Further you need to include the ui-bootstrap-xxx.min.js somewhere in your html.
If you use ui-bootstrap in version >= 0.14 you need to change $modal to $uibModal

Comment: Maybe the other Module which uses your MessageService has already ui.bootstrap as a dependency, but in your current module which uses the MessageService ui.bootstrap is maybe not included.

Comment: I use version 0.12 so I think $modal is right.
The module 'portal.services.messagemanager' works fine - I can call it from another controller without problems.
It is only when I call from "outside" angular that I am missing something.

Comment: I got a bit further by adding 'ui.bootstrap' to this line:
var messagemanagerModule = angular.injector(['ng', 'ui.bootstrap', 'portal.services.messagemanager']);
In the code "outside" angular where I want to use the service. Now I get another unknown provider error, but I properbly just have to find the correct module to inject.

Comment: In the place where you use the javascript snippet, is there the ui.bootstrap-xxx.js loaded? You can check in firebug if it is there

Comment: I think 'ui.bootstrap' gets loaded now when I have added it to the angular.injector modules array.
One of the services uses $location which gives me this error:
Unknown provider: $rootElementProvider <- $rootElement <- $location <- ConfigurationService <- $location
Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: I think you have to add the module which holds the ConfigurationService into your injector too. Further you have to ensure that the js file containing that service is also loaded.

Comment: I finally got it to work by adding a rootElement.
[example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28399456/unknown-provider-rootelementprovider-when-using-injector-to-get-location-ser)
I added the 'mockApp' described in the second example in answer by @PSL